# Quicklook embedded preview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsview

From the docs for quicklook:

> "The consumer portion of Quick Look
>   has three components: a document
>   reader (consisting of a custom view
>   and panel), display bundles for that
>   reader, and an SPI to enable
>   communication with the client. Each of
>   these components has a specific role
>   to play in support of the consumer:
>
> Document reader—Quick Look implements
>   a view (NSView) and panel (NSPanel)
>   customized for displaying document
>   previews. Along with the preview
>   content, the view might include (at
>   the client’s option) controls for
>   manipulating the preview, such as
>   page-forward, page-backward, start
>   playing, rewind, and text-search. **A
>   client application can embed this view
>   in its user interface if it chooses.**
>   The Quick Look panel contains a Quick
>   Look view and various controls that
>   let the user take some action with the
>   preview, such making the preview image
>   full-screen or starting a slideshow."

I have been poring through all the docs and examples for quicklook and I don't see either:

1. A definition of any sort of "Document reader" component or way to access it.
2. Any sort of SPI as such that would show how to consumer quicklook
3. Any direct access to the NSView used by quicklook to display previews.

All I want to to do as the docs say: embed quicklook's view in my own hierarchy rather than in the Panel.  The panel of course has abundant documentation.  Has anyone successfully used Quicklook in this manner before?

Comment: Did QLPreviewView work for you?

Comment: what was the solution you adopted, i am getting error on using QLPreviewView. I am trying to preview local file .

Answer (score 7):

The class you are looking for is `QLPreviewView`, part of `Quartz.framework`.  It's a public class (introduced in Lion, I believe).  <strike>Unfortunately, the docs team apparently hasn't yet released its documentation, which is probably why you couldn't find it.</strike> The [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Quartz/Reference/QLPreviewView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html) are now available.

The short, short version is that you create it the way you would any other view, and set its `previewItem` to an `id <QLPreviewItem>` that you supply.  The `<QLPreviewItem>` protocol [is documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Quartz/Reference/QLPreviewItem_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  E.g.

```
QLPreviewView *pv = [[QLPreviewView alloc] initWithFrame:frame
                                                   style:QLPreviewViewStyleNormal];
[pv setPreviewItem:item];
[myView addSubview:pv];
[pv release];
```

That's the basic concept, YMMV.

Its operation is thoroughly covered in the 2011 WWDC session "System-wide Previews on Mac OS X and iOS" (or something to that effect).  You should be able to get the video if you are a paid member of either the Mac OS X or iOS developer programs.